# how to use i18next-chained-backend plugin for missing key level fallback?

Tags: fallback, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

It seems by default Reacti18next falls back to the translation key if no translation was found in Remote URL which i passed using HTTPBackend loadpath for the key, e.g. // No translation defined for **bill_type_blank** yet i18next.t('*bill_type_blank*') // Returns '**bill_type_blank**' If no translation is found for the key on Remote LoadPath, I would prefer to fetch that same key from locales path "locales/{{lng}}/translation.json". i am already using ChainedBackend for network fallback i want the same for key fallback, How can I achieve something like this using the i18next library?

Comment: i18next fallback (in combination with chained-backend) only works on language and/or namespace level

Comment: @sanjay: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

as @adrai is saying, i18next fallback (in combination with chained-backend) only works on language and/or namespace level.

However i have found out a kind of hacky way, but works like a charm!

First declare a function which loads local files and assign them data into an object:

```
async function getLocalTranslations(
  lng: string,
  namespaces: string[]
): Promise<Record<string, any>> {
  const arr = await Promise.all(
    namespaces.map(async (n) => {
      const data = await import(`./locales/${lng}/${n}.json`);
      return {
        key: n,
        value: data.default,
      };
    })
  );

  return arr.reduce(
    (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }),
    {}
  );
}

const localFiles = await getLocalTranslations(lng, ns);
```

Then use this newly created function into `parseMissingKeyHandler` based on key and namespace missing.

```
 i18next.use(Backend).init(
    {
      debug: false,
      lng,
      defaultNS: ns[0],
      ns,
      fallbackLng: false,
      appendNamespaceToMissingKey: true,
      parseMissingKeyHandler(missingKey) {
        const splitKey = missingKey.split(":");
        const namespace = splitKey.length > 1 ? splitKey[0] : ns[0];
        const key = namespace ? splitKey[1] : splitKey[0];

        return localFiles[namespace][key] ?? missingKey;
      },
      backend: {
        backends: [
          CUSTOMHTTPMODULEHERE,
          resourcesToBackend(
            (language: string, namespace: string) =>
              import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
          ),
        ],
      },
    },
    () => {
      console.log(i18next.t("user.description"));
    }
  );
```

basically the point of all of this is:

1. We use a chained backend which handles fallback in case translation files or namespaces are not found.
2. In order to handle the missing key fallback to local files if the remote url does return an empty or null string, we use the i18n `parseMissingKeyHandler` which will use the **preloaded** local files (see `getLocalTranslations` in my code).

Hope this helps